# Empty text view

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, android-intent, android-studio

I am currently developing an app in android studio.The goal of my app is to have one page(MainActivity.java & activityMain.xml) display a spinner. The items in this spinner are items from a remote database. When the user selects an item in this spinner I want that selected item to be displayed in a separate page(Map.java map.xml). 
I used a putExtra method in MainActivity to store the selected item into a string variable:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Selected" ,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map.class);
    String text = spinnerFood.getSelectedItem().toString();
    intent.putExtra("SPINNER_KEY", text);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Then in my Map class I am calling that string using getExtras:

```
String spinnerString;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            spinnerString= null;
        } else {
            spinnerString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
        }
    } else {
        spinnerString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
```

I can pass this string from MainActivity to Map successfully. My problem is when I try to display this string is does not appear on the XML page or on my phone when I run the app. I used the following code to try and display the string:

```
TextView e = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        e.setText(spinnerString);
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.cillin.infoandroidhivespinnermysql;

import java.util.ArrayList;
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Button btnAddNewCategory;
    private TextView txtCategory;
    public Spinner spinnerFood;
    //public String spinnerValue;

    // array list for spinner adapter
    private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // API urls
    // Url to create new category
    private String URL_NEW_CATEGORY = "http://food_api/new_category.php";
    // Url to get all categories
    private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://food_api/get_categories.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAddNewCategory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewCategory);
        spinnerFood = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFood);
        txtCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);

        categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();

        // spinner item select listener
        spinnerFood.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Add new category click event
        btnAddNewCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (txtCategory.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {

                    // new category name
                    String newCategory = txtCategory.getText().toString();

                    // Call Async task to create new category
                    new AddNewCategory().execute(newCategory);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter category name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        new GetCategories().execute();

    }

    /**
     * Adding spinner data
     * */
    public void populateSpinner() {
        List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

        txtCategory.setText("");

        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
            lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
        }


        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerFood.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        //String text = spinnerFood.getSelectedItem().toString();

    }


    /**
     * Async task to get all food categories
     * */
    private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Fetching food categories..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                                .getJSONArray("categories");

                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                            Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                    catObj.getString("name"));
                            categoriesList.add(cat);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            populateSpinner();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async task to create a new food category
     * */
    private class AddNewCategory extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        boolean isNewCategoryCreated = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating new category..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {

            String newCategory = arg[0];

            // Preparing post params
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", newCategory));

            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();

            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_NEW_CATEGORY,
                    ServiceHandler.POST, params);

            Log.d("Create Response: ", "> " + json);

            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");
                    // checking for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // new category created successfully
                        isNewCategoryCreated = true;
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Create Category Error: ", "> " + jsonObj.getString("message"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            if (isNewCategoryCreated) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // fetching all categories
                        new GetCategories().execute();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Selected" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map.class);
        String text = spinnerFood.getSelectedItem().toString();
        intent.putExtra("SPINNER_KEY", text);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
}
```

Here is Map.java:

```
package com.example.cillin.infoandroidhivespinnermysql;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by cillin on 06/07/2015.
 */
public class Map extends Activity
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //This page layout is located in the menu XML file
        //SetContentView links a Java file, to its XML file for the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        /*Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinFood);
        String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        EditText e = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        e.setText(text);*/

        String spinnerString;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                spinnerString= null;
            } else {
                spinnerString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
            }
        } else {
            spinnerString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
        }
        /*if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle.getString("SPINNER_KEY") != null) {
                spinnerString = bundle.getString("SPINNER_KEY");
            }
        }*/

        //String a = "ddd";

        TextView e = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        e.setText(spinnerString);

        Button mainm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainmenu);
        mainm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //This button is linked to the map page
                Intent i = new Intent(Map.this, MainMenu.class);

                //Activating the intent
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is my map.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/map_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/map"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainmenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop = "450dp"
        android:text="Main Menu" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: instead of asking for debuging help, you should tell what is the error you are getting.... also add only code which is relevant.. no one will read this much of code.

Comment: I am not getting an error though.. That's why im not sure where I am going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `getIntent().getStringExtra("STRING_I_NEED");`

`getIntent.getExtras()` will work only if you pass `Bundle` in calling activity

Comment: That gives me the error: Incompatible types. Required: android.os.Bundle Found: java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
String spinnerString;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            spinnerString= null;
        } else {
            spinnerString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
        }
    } else {
        spinnerString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
```

I changed "STRING_I_NEED" to "SPINNER_KEY"